# What to bear in mind when doing minor update of omega base-theme

Tags: updating, theming

Recently the minor update of [Omega-Theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/omega), version 4.3, has been released. Since i have an omega subtheme based on version 4.2, i would like to know, how i can do the update to version 4.3.
Is it sufficient to just update the base-theme or should i do changes in my subtheme too?

Comment: I think that really depends on what you have overridden in your sub-theme.  I would take a look at the release notes to see what was updated, and check if your sub-theme includes changes to any of the updated sections.